# Are bike frames galvanized

Tags: frames, paint

I'm sorry for the stupid question, but I have a primer that works on steel but specifically says to avoid galvanized metals.  I don't really know how to tell if a metal is galvanized or what use-cases warrant galvanization.

Are steel bike frames typically galvanized?

Bonus question: how do you tell if a steel is galvanized? Is it that weird blotchy look that steel water pipes typically have?

Thank you

Comment: Likely some frames were galvanized 60 years ago, but most better quality frames today aren't even steel, and the steel ones definitely aren't galvanized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of a galvanized frame. Galvanizing involves dipping steel in molten zinc, which I'm pretty sure would mess up the heat treatment state of the steel tubes.

Frames are just painted to protect from corrosion.

Comment: [Here's one](https://www.thelightblue.co.uk/Sport/FMLBDD1K/Darwin-Frame-Set).

Comment: @Klaster_1 - That's the paint color, not the steel treatment.